# Use @XMLTransient in CXF web service with jaxb binding

Tags: jaxb, cxf

I have an application that relies heavily on configuration object (template). So import/export features is a must. One developer has completed the import/export feature and lot of DTOs has been annotated with Jaxb @XMLTransient. The reason for that is we don't want to marshall the id of the object in one DB and import it to another and to prevent circular reference between object.

Now we expose some of the function in the service layer using Cxf with jaxb binding. We don't generate the dto from wsdl but using our current dtos and of course some of the attribute is missing when transport via ws.

My question is how can I solve this problem without touching the existing import/export but still support for the cxf ws.

Any recommendation and idea is much appreciated.